# TFS security - users in both Readers and Contributors groups

Tags: security, tfs

I am trying to setup security in TFS and running into an issue.
We have several team projects and about 30 developers.
We want all developers to have read access to all team projects.
Then there are certain teams which would have read/write access to one or more team projects.

I have an AD group which has all 30 developers and several other AD groups which have the appropriate developers. I assigned the AD group which contains all the developers to the Readers group in each team project. And then the other specific groups as Contributors in their respective team projects.

The problem is that when a user is in both the Readers and Contributors group - it seams as if the Readers group permissions are used (since they are more restrictive). According to the documentation this appears to be the way tfs security is supposed to work.

But how can I set this up properly ?

Comment: This seems surprising to me - in my (default) TFS configuration, Readers and Contributors groups have different "Allow" permissions of course, but no "Deny" permissions.  So I'd expect permissions obtained through membership of the two groups to be additive.  Have you checked what permissions are associated with the "Readers" and "Contributers" groups in your setup?  Are any permissions denied?

Comment: Yes - for example : user XYZ which is in an AD group attached to the Readers group has Deny in all permissions except the Read permission. That same XYZ user is also in another AD group which is attached to the Contributors group which has Allow on every permission.

Comment: In that case, you would to remove the "deny" from the permissions for the Readers group.  If you explicitly deny a permission for one group, it won't be overridden by an allow for another group of which you are a member.

Comment: Permissions of groups are additive, but Deny ist stronger than Allow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old but maybe you will still find it useful.

Assigning all developers to Readers group is a shortcut which you should not take in this case.

I would create a separate group for each group of developers (dived based on projects) and then assign permissions to those groups - similar to contributors for their own project and similar to readers for all other projects.

As for why it didn't work for you - `Deny` permission wins over `Allow` permission if a user has both.

Comment: You can have the developers be in multiple groups and assign those individual AD groups to each team project they need to be contributors of. The Key is that in your security settings to use `Not Set` instead of `Deny`. `Not Set` defaults to `Deny` but it allows for the `Allow` to over write the group. That is how i did things in the past.